# PowerShell: Directory Retrieval and syntax error

Tags: windows, powershell

A little background...
I use Windows XP, Vista, and 7 quite frequently. As such, I constantly have to move my program settings from the `%appdata%` folder on each PC to the next. I figured that making a PowerShell script to do this for me and remove the folders after I finish would be something to ease my troubles. As I generally have my work on a flash drive, I was hoping to use relative paths, but it seems to be causing me a bit of trouble, but the biggest problem is that I don't seem to understand Powershell enough to know what mistake I'm making and how to fix it... So I came here.
I figured that I could separate the task into two scripts; one for placing the directories and the second for copying them back to the original folder and removing any trace of them behind. I'll show you want I have so far. I  figured retrieving them might be more difficult so I started there. Here's what I have so far. I'm using a txt file to make it easy to update the list of folders I want or need transferred so it's also being targeted by a variable.

```
$fldrtxt = Get-Content .\FolderList.txt
$dirget = -LiteralPath ="'%appdata%'\$_fldertxt"
$dirpost = "./Current"
# get-command | Add-Content .\"$today"_CommandList.txt
Set-Location c: {get-content $_dirget} | %{ copy-item $_dirpost}
```

I can't get PowerShell to recognize the same command that I use when I use the run utility. Since I'm sure I can use `%appdata%` to reference where I want the folders taken from and to, how can't I write this script to do what I want? I can use an absolute path, because I'd have to use a separate script for all three computers. And that I don't want.

How can I use PowerShell to do what I want and target the folders I need to use?

Comment: As a general comment, your variable naming is confusing in the world of PowerShell. Variables like $_dirget look strange because many cmdlets offer a special variable $_, which means "the object currently in the pipeline". Thus you may see something like:    get-process | foreach-object { $_.PM/1KB }     ... Given this, naming something $_PM would be a bad idea.

Comment: I will change my practice of the syntax. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First: Accerss the Environment**

> Since I'm sure I can use %appdata% to reference where I want the folders take from and too

Wrong syntax for PowerShell, the `%var%` syntax for environment variables is specific to cmd scripts (and carried forward from MS-DOS batch files).

In PowerShell to access environment variables prefix their name with `env:`, so `$env:AppData`.

```
$_dirget = "$env:AppData\$_fldertxt"
```

**Second: Passing parameters**

Don't include the parameter name in the variable, a variable passed to a cmdlet will be passed as an argument not a parameter name. You need:

```
get-content -LiteralPath $_dirget
```

(There is something call "splat" that allows you to use a hash tables of parameter name-argument pairs as a hashtable, but that's unnecessary here.)

Comment: Actually environment variables that uses the $env variable are fully expandable without enclosing them in a sub-expression, this should work: "$env:AppData\$_fldertxt"

Comment: @ShayLevy So it does... I wonder where I got it stuck in my mind that a sub-expression was needed? Will update the answer.

Comment: I was thinking I might need to do that, but I wasn't sure exactly how. I'll try this out and see how it goes. Thanks for your help.